# timer that runs 2 of every 3 seconds c#

Tags: c#, timer

Is there a way to run a program every two of three seconds? I know you can make timers run every n milliseconds, but not every n of m seconds. For a very basic example, pretend I want to have two functions that both add to an integer value. One function would run two of every three seconds and add 5 to some value. The second function would add 100 to the same value, but would only run that one second that the other one doesn't run. Does this make sense?

Comment: So you would want timer A to run, wait one second, run wait two seconds, then repeat, and then timer B to wait two seconds before running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way would be to keep an internal representation of which second you were on and switch based on it to a different execution.

```
private int counter = 0;
private int whichSecond = 0;

void RunsEverySecond()
{
    if (whichSecond < 2)
    {
        counter += 5;
        whichSecond++;
    }
    else
    {
        counter += 100;
        whichSecond = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is perfect! Exactly what I wanted! Thanks